# Sharepoint online - site pages vs blog post - is it set up correctly

Tags: sharepoint-online, blog

A third party vendor has installed O365 sharepoint, having migrated from SP13 and Im used to the layout and file structure of the blog system (boy do i miss it), new posts are now being submitted as 'site pages'[image: Red boxes = blog posts and green boxes = standard pages]

In both instances, a new page/post must be created - but they both appear to be a blank page and on each occasion I need to add the same elements back in.

Apologies in advance if I should provide more screenshots or context; please can someone advise me on this

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You do not set up blog system correctly according to your description.

You could create a subsite and choose the “blog” site template. And the home page of the blog is like the picture.

It will not submit the new posts to the “site pages” library in the blog system.

[image]

[image]